# What do I need to know to calculate the price per km for plug-in hybrid or electric cars?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy

Knowing the per kWh price of electricity, what other factors are needed to calculate how much would one pay per km traveled on electric power compared to gasoline power?
EDIT: For example, the [Chevrolet Volt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chevrolet_Volt) reports a 35 kWh per 100 miles. Supposing the price for electricity is 11 cents per kWh, so this mean one can drive 100 miles for $3.85, or a mile for 3.8 cents?

Comment: How would you calculate the price per km knowing only the price per kWh?

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the kWh used per km, obviously.

If apples are $.50 each, what cost in apples/day do you use?  You need to know how many apples/day you eat, which again should be obvious.